# Wrapper for Kibana visualizations?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Does Kibana have any kind of wrapper so that it could be exposed to a user for creating visualization dashboards without giving the user any actual access to kibana?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up this using the X-pack extension. With the standard version, you won't be able to forbid access on particular parts of your Kibana.